# Image preview on hover direction aware?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help :)

Working on a portfolio website with an image preview when you hover over a portfolio title. Whenever I hover over de last few titles at the bottom of the page, there are some ugly glitches/bounces: the image escapes the bounds of the webpage. Is there a way to make it direction aware, so that when you hover over the last few titles the image preview shows up above the title instead of below?

The HTML:

```
<ul class="project-list">
    <li>
        <a href="" rel="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="preview" title="" target="_self">Title Here</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
#preview {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    max-width: 50rem;
    height: auto;
}
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    imagePreview();
});

// Configuration of the x and y offsets
this.imagePreview = function(){ 
        xOffset = -30;
        yOffset = 40;   

    var imgHeight = 0;
    var distFromTop = 0;
    var mainImgTop = $(".preview").position();  

    $(".preview").hover(function(e){
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";

        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img style='display:block;' src='"+ this.rel +"' alt='Image prev' />");

        $("#preview")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("slow");
    },

    function(){
        this.title = this.t;
        $("#preview").remove();
    });

    $(".preview").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });
};
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/spacebot/b7h46cfh/

Comment: and your JSfiddle ?

Comment: @IamSilviu sorry, updated!

Comment: You can use collision detection from jquery UI  .position() https://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the image above the last X amount of titles, you can use :nth-last-child(-n+X) (where X is the amount of titles).

Check if the title is one of the last titles and run another animation to show the image above.

```
//If link is one of the last 3 childs, open above
if($(this).is(':nth-last-child(-n+3)')){ 
    openAbove();
}
```

JSFiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/447pjobL/8/